# Lua: %b with modifiers

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, string-parsing

I'm trying to match a string that contains Lua code.

```
a = [[workspace.Object["Child"]:remove()]]
```

to do this, I'm trying to create an option where either `.x` or `['x']` would be matched regardless of what order they are in or how many of them there are.

A couple problems I have run into:

- How do I match more than one combined character/pattern between brackets? `[abc]` matches `a` or `b` or `c`, but not `abc`.
- How do I add a modifier to `%b[]`? ex. `%b[]+` to match `['x']['x']['x']`
- If I could match something like `%[.-%] *`, that would work the same.

Comment: What do you want your `match` or `find` to return?

Comment: I'm not looking to capture anything, I just wait it to be able to recognize any combination of x.y.z and x[y][z] and x[y].z.w[v] etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua does not fully support regexps.
But you can do your task step-by-step, using intermediate strings.

```
local str0 = [[workspace.Object["Child"]['xx'][5].xxx:remove()]]
local str = str0
   :gsub('%b[]',
      function(s)
         return s:gsub('^%[%s*([\'"]?)(.*)%1%s*%]$','{%2}')
      end
   )
   :gsub('[%.:]%s*([%w_]+)','{%1}')

print(str0)
print(str)
print()
for w in str:gmatch'{(.-)}' do
   print(w)
end

---------------------------
-- output
---------------------------
workspace.Object["Child"]['xx'][5].xxx:remove()
workspace{Object}{Child}{xx}{5}{xxx}{remove}()

Object
Child
xx
5
xxx
remove
```

---

**EDIT :**

```
local str0 = [[workspace.Object["Child"]['xx'][5][ [=[xxx]=] ]:remove()]]
local str = str0
   :gsub('%b[]',
      function(s)
         return s:gsub('^%[%s*([\'"]?).*%1%s*%]$','{%0}')
      end
   )
   :gsub('%.%s*[%w_]+','{%0}')
   :gsub(':%s*[%w_]+%s*([\'"]).-%1','{%0}')
   :gsub(':%s*[%w_]+%s*%b()','{%0}')
   :gsub('{(:%s*remove%s*%(%s*%))}','%1')
   :gsub('}%s*{', '')
   :gsub('([%w_]+)%s*(%b{})%s*:%s*remove%s*%(%s*%)',
      function(s1, s2)
         return 'removefilter('..s1..s2:match'^{(.*)}$'..')'
      end
   )
   :gsub('([%w_]+)%s*:%s*remove%s*%(%s*%)','removefilter(%1)')
   :gsub('[{}]', '')

print(str0)
print(str)

---------------------------
-- output
---------------------------
workspace.Object["Child"]['xx'][5][ [=[xxx]=] ]:remove()
removefilter(workspace.Object["Child"]['xx'][5][ [=[xxx]=] ])
```

Comment: The ["']? is necessary, but what about cases where strings are in brackets; ex. [[string]], [=[string]=], [======etc.

Comment: Yes, where things would be written as, [[[Child]]] or [[=[Child]=]] rather than ["Child"]
Another question though: How would this be read? Would it see the [[ ]] and think =[Child]= is the string, or would it see the [ ] and think it must be indexing something and [=[ ]=] is indicating that Child must be the string?

Comment: @Waffle - `Object[[[Child]]]` is not a correct Lua expression.

Comment: @Waffle - `Object[[=[Child]=]]` is attempt to call a function `Object('=[Child]=')`.

Comment: Since it has .*, it would catch [([[Child]])] anyway, so it doesn't matter. What I was initially trying to do was to filter the :remove() method and turn it into a function, where workspace.Object:remove() would turn into removefilter(workspace.Object). I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that given what I currently know how to do.

Comment: Well that works (but not in cases of object:remove() alone). Sometimes an object may have a method that will return another object. That method may or may not be called with parenthesis. The argument(s) within that method may or may not be a string if they exist. So I would need to add {:method()} and {:method''} and {:method""} etc. to that.