# Lua String patterns - shorter code

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

Is it possible to take this:

```
a=[[do end workspace.Part["Child 1"].Object.child2["thing"]remove() do end]]
a=a:gsub("%.%a+","{F}%0{F}")  
a=a:gsub('(%[%s*([\'"]?).*%2%s*%]):remove%(%)','{F}%1{F}:remove()')
a=a:gsub('{F}%s*{F}','')
a=a:gsub('{F}.-{F}','filterremove(%0)')

Output: do end filterremove(Workspace.Part["Child 1"].Object.child2["thing"]) do end
```

and use only one gsub to have the same result, rather than two?
regardless of the combination of x.y, x[y], [x][y], etc.

Comment: Provide the sample input and output strings?

Comment: Input: workspace.Part["Child"]:remove(), Output: filterremove(workspace.Part["Child"])

Comment: `a=a:gsub("(.*)%:remove%(%)", "filterremove(%1)")` <- works fine.

Comment: That will try to put the entire program up to 'remove' into one function.

Comment: You need to update the output to match the updated input.

Comment: [Relevant](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Sandboxing). You can't get there from here.

Comment: You can't keep moving the goalpost. Isn't this *now* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115438/lua-b-with-modifiers? Or are you asking for a simpler way to do the same thing?

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to combine two complicated string patterns. I just happen to be using a similar example.

Comment: You might want to check out the [LPeg library](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/). It lets you have multiple patterns "in parallel" as well as many other advanced features. It can be a bit tricky to use at first though.

Answer (score 1):

`a:gsub("(%S*%b[]):remove%(%)", "filterremove(%1)")`

Comment: I know, but then you need to specify an example you want to see working. Or several examples. As soon as someone comes up with implementation that satisfies them, you get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least chain and line-wrap it:

```
a = [[do end workspace.Part["Child 1"]:remove() do end]]
a = a:gsub("%.%a+","{F}%0{F}")  
     :gsub('(%[%s*([\'"]?).*%2%s*%]):remove%(%)','{F}%1{F}:remove()')
     :gsub('{F}%s*{F}','')
     :gsub('{F}.-{F}','filterremove(%0)')
```

Really though, this is never going to work. What about:

```
workspace.remove(x)
workspace["remove"](x)
getfenv()["work" .. "space"]["re".."move"](x)
```

Comment: and what about spaces: `workspace . Part["..."] :remove()`; OP needs to make at least some assumptions...

Comment: @Paul: I don't think the OP can afford to make any assumptions, since they are almost certainly trying to sandbox unknown code.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, but if that's the case these attempts are futile.

Comment: Spaces are not a problem. %s*, now forget about it. Concatenation and variables where I can't catch whether or not it is using 'remove' is the problem.